# How can I change the Google Play Console language?

Tags: google-play

How can I change the Google Play Console language? Here you can see that the language is not English:

[image]

Comment: Have you checked your default preferred language in your Google Account settings? [This](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/table/4419860?hl=en) help page seems to suggest that you could change it there.

Answer (score 27):

From the [Google Support Page](https://support.google.com/a/answer/43212?hl=en):

> The Admin console uses the same language you choose in your Account settings.

So to change the language you have to change your language in account settings. To do this follow these steps (from [Google Support](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32047) again):

> 1. Sign in to your account.
> 2. In the "Account preferences" section, select **Language & Input Tools**.
> 3. Choose **Language**.
> 4. To change your language, select edit **Edit** [image: edit image].
> 5. Choose your language from the dropdown box and select **Ok**.

Comment: i didn't find such menu.. but solved by changing language at the login page (bottom left, below the login form)

Comment: That might change, but right now that page is https://myaccount.google.com/language

Answer (score 22):

In the url change hl=ru to hl=en.

Comment: Hi duo, and welcome to GameDev.StackExchange! While this answer may correctly solve the issue, you might find your answers attract more upvotes if you also include a little more explanation of why it works.

Comment: You are a lifesaver!!! Does anyone know why this happens?

Answer (score 5):

Nowadays, i could not see language prefs on Google Play Console. Instead of Play Console, you can change language via [Google Account](https://myaccount.google.com.). After you click on it,

- Click **Data & personalization**,
- Scroll down the page until the
  **General preferences for the web** title and then you will see the **Language** preference. You can change account language with this way.

After you completed steps above, Go to [Play Console](https://play.google.com/apps/publish). You will see the portal language which was changed.

Comment: This worked for me. For precise steps, take a look at [Change your Google Admin console language](https://support.google.com/a/answer/43212?hl=en)

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by changing URL only. As it is a client account, I don't want to mess things up for  him by changing whole account language so I only add parameter `hl=en` in the URL.

For example, change this:

- `https://play.google.com/apps/publish/?account=`

Into this:

- `https://play.google.com/apps/publish/?hl=en&account=`

Comment: This works. The easiest way.

Comment: Refresh the page and it's gone.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue and changing account settings language didn't help. But I solved it by changing default Chrome language. So if you tried changing your account language settings and it didn't work, go to chrome://settings/languages and move your preferred language to the top. Reload page and it should work